# Error Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to obtain a calculation for salesman bonus as per their level of experience(1-4) as an integer, and what they have sold (1-10000) as decimal. Why am I getting this error now? Here is the code...

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim intLvlsTextBox1Numbers As String = Nothing And intLvlsTextBox1Numbers = txtBoxLvl.Text
    Dim decSaleWkTextBox1Numbers As String = Nothing And decSaleWkTextBox1Numbers = txtBoxWklySale.Text

    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        'The Try/Catch method is used to catch the "InvalidCastExceptionUnhandeled" in order to use the 
        'exception for detecting letters within the textboxes being understood in logic as of
        'a wrong type, thus enabling its detection as letter or caracter.
        Try
            intLvlsTextBox1Numbers = Convert.ToInt32(txtBoxLvl.Text)
            decSaleWkTextBox1Numbers = Convert.ToInt32(txtBoxWklySale.Text)
            'This line is used to validate indetify non-valid data input upon entring numbers
            'that are out of rang, and will display the warning error message. It goes from 
            'anything not convertable to Integer 32, i.e. letter, signs.
            MessageBox.Show("Please, input a numerical value")
            'Reset the cursor position when a non-valid data is inputed.
            txtBoxLvl.Select()
            'Catches the EX variable execption,"InvalidCastExceptionUnhandeled".
        Catch ex As FormatException

        End Try

        'procedure call to the ChoiceMenus
        ChoiceMenus()

    End Sub
    Private Sub ChoiceMenus()
        Select Case intLvlsTextBox1Numbers
            Case 1 To 4
        End Select
        Select Case decSaleWkTextBox1Numbers
            Case 1 To 100000
        End Select
    End Sub
    Private Sub isValidCalculation()
        lblTotWkSale.Text = 250 * (intLvlsTextBox1Numbers + 1) + ((intLvlsTextBox1Numbers + 1) / 100) * (decSaleWkTextBox1Numbers)
        decSaleWkTextBox1Numbers = Convert.ToString(lblTotWkSale.Text)
        lblTotWkSale.Text = decSaleWkTextBox1Numbers.ToString("c")
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnClr_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClr.Click

        clearForm() 'procedure call

    End Sub

    Private Sub clearForm()
        txtBoxWklySale.Text = ""
        txtBoxLvl.Text = ""
        lblTotWkSale.Text = ""
        lblErrorMsg.Text = ""
        txtBoxLvl.Select()
        'tbxHome = True
        'tbx1 = True
        'tbx2 = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click

        Me.Close() 'closes the application
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the use of `Convert.ToInt32`. This function requires a object that implements the `IConvertible` interface. Else it throws a `InvalidCastException`.

What you want to do is parse a `String` to a `Int32`. Doing to works best with `Int32.Parse` or `Int32.TryParse`. The latter works good if you are unsure if the input is really a decimal value.

So in the end this is want you want to do:

```
intLvlsTextBox1Numbers = Int32.Parse(txtBoxLvl.Text)
decSaleWkTextBox1Numbers = Int32.Parse(txtBoxWklySale.Text)
```

Comment: That's not it.  The error message is not InvalidCastException

Answer (score 1):

```
 Dim intLvlsTextBox1Numbers As String = Nothing And intLvlsTextBox1Numbers = txtBoxLvl.Text
```

The way you initialized the fields is very creative.  Although I can't understand what it is supposed to do.  The runtime doesn't either, it will bomb your program with NRE when the form's constructor runs.  Hard to diagnose because the debugger doesn't have a good line to show you.  It fails because the txtBoxLvl variable isn't initialized yet, that won't happen until later, after InitializeComponent() runs.  Sadly also something that vb.net hides.

Try to write more sane code, the kind you can find in a decent book about vb.net programming.  These variables should not be fields in your form class at all, they should be local variables in the method:

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
     Dim intLvlsTextBox1Numbers As Integer '' It is not a string!!
     Dim levelOk = Integer.TryParse(txtBoxLvl.Text, intLvlsTextBox1Numbers)
     If Not levelOk Then
         '' complain...
         Return
     End If
     '' etc...
End Sub
```